# import statement to create a session object in android

Tags: android, session

In android, I want to create a session object.
I saw a statment in one of the post as follow;
public static Session mySessionObject = new Session(); 
where can i get the import statment?

I simple want to have a client base login that manages session.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

```
 Session session = new Session();
 Properties props = new Properties();
 session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
```

then you can add

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
```

Comment: I think i am missing an import statement because when i tried Session session = new Session(); eclipse does not reconginze it.

Comment: put this after props :                                             Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);         and remove  Session session = new Session();

Comment: I am looking for something like import javax.servlet.HttpSession but Android version.  When I change the location of the instantiation of Session, it does not seem to reconginize it.

Answer (score 0):

The android framework doesn't have any Session class. Ask the author of that code, what he used there.
If you don't have special needs, you can write your own Session class.

Comment: How do I write my own session class. All the example I saw calls HTTP SESSION but I just want to manage login locally.

Comment: What does this mean exactly? Do you want to drop the user out after a certain time?